# If my monitor has no MacOS driver available, do I have any other options for adjusting overscan? | macbook 2017

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

I have a 2017 13" MacBook Pro -- I just setup my monitors, connected via two usb-c to hdmi dongles. One of my monitors works fine (ViewSonic VS2450), but the other extends the desktop beyond the edges of the monitor (HP 2509m).

I checked the HP site for my monitor, and there are only Windows drivers available. I didn't have to install any drivers for the ViewSonic monitor to work.

Do I have any other options to correct the overscan?

Comment: You sure this is overscan in OSX and not just an aspect ratio issue in the Monitor settings? Try change the aspect ratio using the physical buttons on the Monitor itself to see if that might solve the issue.

Comment: Have you checked Display preferences? With HDMI out there should be an Overscan slider; is it not there?

Comment: @hrdy - Yeah the monitor has worked with everything else prior to the macbook. No physical settings seem to do anything.

Comment: @timothymh, I see no slider (maybe due to missing drivers?)

Answer (score 1):

On the 2509m there is a button that says "Auto" and immediately underneath it says "OK".  When you press this button the display will throw up a text boxy that says "Auto-Adjustment in Progress" and that should correct your overscan issue.  I just discovered that by accident. :)